# How can I refactor this method with streams/ lambdas?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I want to use Streams and Lambdas.
But how can I rewrite my current method with it?

```
 public double calculate() {
            double result = 0.0;

            if (!mediumList.isEmpty()) {
                Iterator<Medium> it = mediumList.iterator();                          
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    result= result+ it.next().getAge();
                }
                result = result / mediumList.size();
            }
       return result;
}
```

Comment: what is `Medium`, and `mediumList`?

Comment: @PatrickParker and how do you know now what `Medium` is?  ...the point was to get the info missing.

Comment: No its not me. Sorry for the disappointment. Though I can neutralize things, but yet would not be apt enough to upvote unless I see the usefulness. Also coming back to the point, ... *return type of getAge* ... I would appreciate if the relative implementation of `Medium` would have been shown here. Surely downvoting the question for that reason. :)

Comment: @nullpointer I think we can assume this code compiles and `getAge()` returns an `int` (as it did in a previous question) or a `double` It surely doesn't return a `String` or `BigDecimal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume `Medium` `age` is an `int`, you could `map` each `medium` in a stream by calling `getAge` and then `sum` it. Like,

```
public double calculate() {
    return mediumList.stream().mapToInt(Medium::getAge).sum() / 
            (double) mediumList.size();
}
```

Comment: Note: Using `average()` may be simpler than using `sum()` and dividing.

Answer (score 6):

You can use IntStream.average()

```
return mediumList.stream()
       .mapToInt(Medium::getAge) // mapToInt makes it an IntStream of the ages
       .average()                // get the average of the ages.
       .orElse(Double.NaN);      // otherwise use Double.NaN if the list is empty.
```

You need to use `mapToInt` to make it an IntSTream so it can be averaged or summed. If you use just `map` you can get `Stream<Integer>` but this doesn't have `sum` or `average` functions.

Comment: though I am not the downvoter here. Keeping that aside, why would we need to mapToInt here could you please explain that or link to any other post that explains it.

Comment: @nullpointer Thank you, after using Java 8 for 3 years I forget what is worth explaining.

Comment: out of curiosity, do you expect this to be much faster than averagingDouble?

Comment: @PatrickParker Using a Collector seems overkill here imho, but it appears that `average()` uses `collect` all the same. ;)

Comment: Considering the OP’s original code, `.orElse(0.0);` would reproduce the same behavior. But it’s worth rethinking whether `NaN`, like in this answer, would be more appropriate. That depends on the context.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, this returns `0.0` if mediumList is empty:

```
return mediumList.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(Medium::getAge));
```